# Modelling roll-over and roll yield in a forward strategy

Tags: futures, forward, roll-adjustment

This is a post which serves as a follow-up question to [Nature of short VIX strategies](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38514/nature-of-short-vix-strategies). I am trying to understand where the change in value in a synthetic strategy constructed from futures comes from:

- Roll-over;
- Roll yield.

Below I display a simplified framework to try to quantify these different factors. We will assume deterministic rates hence forward and futures prices coincide.

**Model**

We are interested in a non-traded asset $X_t$. We assume there is a liquid forward market for asset $X_t$ for some maturities $\{T_i:i = 1, \dots, n\}$. The price at time $t_0$ of a forward of maturity $T_i$ is given by $F(t_0,T_i)$ and its value at $t>t_0$ by:

$$ V_F(t,t_0,T_i)=X_t-F(t_0,T_i)B(t,T_i) $$

where $B(t,T_i)$ is the value of a zero-coupon bond maturing in $T_i$. We assume a constant rate $r_F$ implied by the asset's forward term structure:

$$ dB(t,T_i) = r_FB(t,T_i)dt $$

Importantly, we assume that $r_F>0$ hence the term structure of the asset is in **contango**, meaning:

$$ \forall \ t_0<T_i<T_j<T_n \ , \quad X_{t_0}<F(t_0,T_i)<F(t_0,T_j)$$

Let us consider a strategy $S_t$ which gives a **short** forward exposure to asset $X_t$ with a horizon of $T_S$ $-$ e.g. 30 days $-$ through forwards. We assume the strategy is initiated at a time $t_0$ and that there is a traded forward maturity $T_1$ such that:

$$ T_S=T_1-t_0$$

Hence at inception the strategy is constructed by shorting a quantity $w^{(1)}_{t_0}$ of forwards with price $F(t_0,T_1)$ and its value is:

$$ S_{t_0} = w^{(1)}_{t_0}V_F(t_0,t_0,T_1)$$

Note that $w^{(1)}_{t_0}\leq 0$ because we are short the asset.

**Roll-over**

Now let us consider some time $dt$ passes. The effective maturity of the  strategy is now lower than $T_S$. We then need to trade in the "next" forward with maturity $T_2$ and:

- hold $w^{(1)}_{t_0+dt} \leq 0$ units of forwards of maturity $T_1$; and
- hold $w^{(2)}_{t_0+dt} \leq 0$ units of forwards of maturity $T_2$

so as to keep an effective strategy maturity of $T_S$. The value of the strategy after rebalancing at $t_0+dt$ is:

$$S_{t_0+dt}=w^{(1)}_{t_0+dt}V_F(t_0+dt,t_0,T_1)+w^{(2)}_{t_0+dt}V_F(t_0+dt,t_0+dt,T_2)$$

Now, we require:

1. the effective maturity of the strategy to be equal to $T_S$;
2. the strategy needs to be self-financing;

Because we have 2 unknowns, namely the 2 weights for each forward, and 2 constraints we can determine values for $w^{(1)}_{t_0+dt}$ and $w^{(2)}_{t_0+dt}$. *Because the strategy is self-financing, the roll-over has no impact on its value*.

[Edit 21/04/2020] More intuitively, note that also that forwards/futures are entered at 0 cost: while you are scaling-down your front-end position, you are entering into offsetting positions at 0 cost, while the shift to the next-month future is also done at 0 cost, thus the process of rolling over does not generate by itself any PnL.

**Roll yield**

Replacing $t_0+dt$ by $t_1$ to avoid (mathematical) confusion, because the strategy is self-financing we have (note that $F(t_k,T_i)$ is contractually defined at inception hence fixed throughout the trade):

$$ \begin{align}
dS_t & = w^{(1)}_{t}dV_F(t,t_0,T_1) + w^{(2)}_{t}dV_F(t,t_1,T_2)
\\[3pt]
& = w^{(1)}_{t}(dX_t-r_FF(t_0,T_1)B(t,T_1)dt) + w^{(2)}_{t}(dX_t-r_FF(t_1,T_2)B(t,T_2)dt)
\end{align} $$

Ignoring the asset's fluctuations, we define the *roll yield* as:

$$ -r_Fw^{(1)}_{t}F(t_0,T_1)B(t,T_1)dt - r_Fw^{(2)}_{t}F(t_1,T_2)B(t,T_2)dt \geq 0 $$

The last inequality stems from the fact that $w^{(i)}_t\leq 0$ because the strategy is short.

**Conclusion**

From the analysis above I conclude the following:

- The value of strategies, such as ETFs or ETNs, that offer synthetic exposure to some asset through the forward/futures market is **not** impacted by forward/futures roll-over **because** they need to be self-financing. Indeed, if they were not self-financing they might require the investor to pour in additional cash throughout the life of the trade which is not the case for ETFs or ETNs.
- The value of these strategies is positively (or negatively, depending on the term structure and whether they are long or short) impacted by the roll yield. For example, in a contangoed market a short forward exposure generates a positive roll yield.

**Are the conclusions above correct? Have I missed some important factor in my analysis, or is there something incorrect?**

Comment: Hi Daneel. Not sure I follow everything. i) Why consider a non-traded asset? ii) I assume this asset does not generate capital distributions and that you could write - if it was traded + AOA - that: $V_F(t,t_0,T_i) = B(t,T_i) ( F(t,T_i) - F(t_0,T_i) )$ showing that $V_F(t_0,t_0,T_i) = 0$ for any $i$ ? To generate an exposure of effective maturity $T_S$ while entering a forward agreement at $T_1 > T_S$ how do you pick the weight $w_{t_0}^{(1)}$ ? By that I mean that as time passes and $T_1$ becomes smaller than $T_S$ you can then simply let $F_1$ expire and just enter $F_2$ with the same rule?

Comment: @Quantuple i) I am thinking of VIX; ii) indeed, no capital distributions for simplicity; you can write that, with deterministic rates we have $X_t=E_t^Q[B(t,T_i)X_{T_i}]=B(t,T_i)E_t^Q[X_{T_i}]=B(t,T_i)F(t,T_i)$ where $F$ can be a future or a forward; finally in my simplified reasoning and changing $t_0$ by $T_0$, we can assume that for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $T_{i+1}-T_i=T_S$ so that at $t=T_i$ you let the $F_i$ future/forward expire and you are fully allocated in the $F_{i+1}$ future/forward, then start rebalancing with $F_{i+2}$ as the effective maturity goes below $T_S$ and so on.

Comment: i bis) The idea is that the forward term structure of the asset, being non-traded, can be "dislocated" from the spot value of the asset, as it seems it is the case with VIX (as far as I know at least).

Comment: @Quantuple The "non-traded" assumption was motivated by the fact that I am interested in the VIX, but we can also assume it is traded, on top of my head I don't know if that changes much. My main concern is with the analysis of roll-over and roll yield, namely that 1) roll-over is value-neutral only if the strategy is self-financing, and 2) how roll yield is generated.

Comment: @Quantuple: Would you like to take a look at my question https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/38719/6686? Thank you.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw, thanks. What do you mean by "effective maturity date $T_s$", mathematically. For instance, what is the value of $w_{t_0}^1$. As I understand it, it's $-1$ (short 1 future contract at  entered at $t_0$). Then, you reach time $t_1$ for which $T_1<=T_S$ and you need to roll. At this point, you can either unwind your position (at zero cost by definition) or let it expire and you'll have locked up on your margin account $w_{t_0}^1(X_{t_1}-F(t_0,T_1))$. Then what you do is short the next front future of $T_2$, this is done at zero cost and you're back at the original situation?

Comment: @Quantuple yes the weight is $-1$ at $t_0$ (it could be equal to $-1\times N$ for some notional $N$ but let's keep it simple). I see what you mean, so I guess I would unwind part of the position at $t_1$ and simultaneously enter at $0$ cost into a position $w^{(2)}_{t_1}$ of $F_2$ to keep the effective maturity. But something I totally missed is that as you say the strategy would yield cash-flows at $T_1$, $T_2$, etc. (Cont'd)

Comment: To explain "effective maturity": if I want a forward exposure of $30$ days to an asset, I can start by trading a $30$-days future, but as time passes what I am being exposed to is the asset $29$-days forward, $28$-days forward, $27$-days forward, etc. So I need to trade into, let's say, the $60$-days forward to keep an average constant maturity of $30$ days. **What I am trying to model here are the synthetic forward strategies constructed to gain exposure to assets such as VIX, that are sold to investors through vehicles such as ETFs**.

Comment: Yes that's what I understood but I'm not familliar with the way they implement such strategies. Okay, so basically you want your weights to be such that $w_t^1 T_1 + w_t^2 T_2 = T_S$ ? How do you do that at $t_0$ with only one future expiring at $T_1 > T_S$? Shouldn't you already start at $t_0$ with 2 futures $T_i$ and $T_{i+1}$ such that $T_i < T_S < T_{i+1}$ ?

Comment: @Quantuple the equation is slightly different: $w^1_t(T_1-t)+w_t^2(T_2-t)=T_S$. I think there might be some misnaming on my side, $T_i$ are dates whereas $T_S$ is a period, a duration. In anyway, yes we can also start the strategy with the 2 futures $F_1$ and $F_2$, there is no particular reason to start just with $F_1$.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw, yeah I figured that don't worry :) I actually wrote everything with $\tau = T - t$ in mind.